# Spring Boot + hibernate Entity is not Mapped

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, jpa, repository

I have problem how to write CustomQuery with Many to One relation.

Opinions Entity:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "Opinions")
public class OpinionsModel implements Serializable {

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
private Long Opinie_id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="productId")
private ProductModel productModel;

private String Comment;

private Double Rate;
```

}

Product Entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Product")
public class ProductModel{

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long productId;

    private String productName;

    private String short_Description;

    private String long_Description;

    private Boolean slider;

    private Boolean discount;

    private double old_Price;

    private double new_Price;

    private String image;
}
```

Opinions Respository:

```
@Repository
public interface OpinionsRepository extends JpaRepository<OpinionsModel,Long> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM Opinions c WHERE c.ProductModel.productId = ?1")
    List<OpinionsModel> getOpinionToProduct();

}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Opinions is not mapped

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Opinions is not mapped [SELECT c FROM Opinions c WHERE c.ProductModel.productId = ?1]
```

My database is in Mysql. nativeQuery on this works fine, bo i want to do it on @Query.

Native Query which works:

```
@Query(value = "select * from opinions where opinions.product_id = :1", nativeQuery = true)
List<OpinionsModel> getOpinionToProduct();
```

The queries I have in non-foreign key fields work well, e.g .:

```
@Query("select p from ProductModel p WHERE p.slider = :state")
List<ProductModel> productOnSlider(Boolean state);

@Query("select p from ProductModel p WHERE p.slider = :sliderState AND p.discount = :DiscountState")
List<ProductModel> productOnDiscount(Boolean sliderState,Boolean DiscountState);
```

Can someone tell me what i did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Opinions")
public class OpinionsModel implements Serializable {
```

The `@Table(name = "Opinions")` means that the table would be named `Opinions` in database. Not that the JPA layer and Hibernate would recognize the entity as `Opinions`. The entity is still known as `OpinionsModel` in JPA layer.

So the following query is wrong

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Opinions c WHERE c.ProductModel.productId = ?1")
```

The correct one is

```
 @Query("SELECT c FROM OpinionsModel c WHERE c.ProductModel.productId = ?1")
```

If you still want the entity to be named `Opinions` and use the existing query you can do 1 of the following:

- Refactor the class OpinionsModel and rename it into Opinions.
- Add the `@Entity(name="Opinions")` to your existing class named OpinionsModel.

Comment: Still doesnt work, now the exception is:  could not resolve property: ProductModel of: computershop.model.OpinionsModel

Comment: @asdasdas please read my answer carefully and try to understand it. Probably you have other similar error in your code which you need to correct.

Comment: The original error was eliminated which means that the topic of the question is solved